# Stirling approximation of logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have faced a limit problem of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln n!$. Now according to Stirling's approximation, we know for very large n, $\ln n!=n\ln n-n$. Now which one of the following two are correct?   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln n!=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n\ln n-n)$$ or $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln n!=(n\ln n-n)$$?

Comment: The second one is a sequence, but the limit is a number in $\tilde{R}$.

Comment: So, the Stirling approximation has nothing to do with limits? then, why do we say, for large n? Expecting a little clarification, sir?

Comment: This limit has a simple result: $+\infty$, you don't have to use Stirling approximation

Comment: The second one makes no sense as $n$ is a bound variable on the left and free on the right.